# the world where we live in now

Tags: grammar, present-tense, present-continuous

I am writing a short article on the subject Today's World. I want to express the fact that – for example – there is the world of poor and the world of rich and successful and so on.

I would like to ask what is the better choice of usage of present tense in this sentence?

> There is not one world where we live in now.

or

> There is not one world where we are living in now.

Comment: In what context are you using the sentence, could you provide the rest of the paragraph that it is used in? Currently, the sentence seems to have lots of problems

Comment: I shall write a short article on the subject Today's World. I want to express the fact that – for example – there is the world of poor and the world of rich and succesful and so on. – Can you be concrete in terms of the grammatical problems in the sentence(s). Thanks

Comment: "There is not just one world in which we live now" sounds good to me. "Where" and "in", when combined in a sentence like this featuring a relative clause, become "in which". Even better though, I might propose a more natural-sounding phrase: "We are now living in more than one world."

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on your reply to your comment I think I see the context that you are writing in now.
You don't really have many major grammatical errors, it's just that the sentence structure is unusual. If I was to rephrase it to sound more natural I would say:

> *We no longer live in one world.*

If you wanted to keep it closer to your examples, I would say:

> The world in which we now live is no longer one.

But I would say that the first example fits the situation better and is also more natural. The phrases you suggested were 'clunky' is all.

Comment: I'd say that using 'where we live in' (i.e., the OP's sentence) is absolutely a grammar error.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use either of your suggested sentences. A natural way to write what you want is

"The world in which we live."

The word "now" is unnecessary, since the present tense means "now" in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I find the usage of "There is not one" to be a bit problematic here.  You want to express the fact that the world is not unified, but it comes across as "the world does not exist".  With a bit of guesswork, I can still understand what you are trying to say, but it's awkward.

Rather, I would reword the entire sentence:

> We do not all live in the same world.

For such an abstract concept, I would use the simple present tense rather than present continuous.

(If you feel that the word "one" is essential to the image you want to paint, I suggest: "We may all live on one planet, but we do not all live in the same world.")